# Channel Listing in Google TV not showing channels

Tags: android, google-tv

I'm testing Googl's 'Channel Changing Example' on my Sony Google TV.
I'm connected to a DVB (Digital Video Broadcasting) through the HDMI port.
When i'm running the example the number of retrieved channels is 0.

Just to be clear, I can see the TV channels using the 'Live TV' in the TV itself.

Comment: Please read FAQ
if your question generally covers …
a specific programming problem
a software algorithm
software tools commonly used by programmers
practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your selected device has a channel lineup. Based on the fact that you're using DVB, I'm guessing you're not in the US, which means you aren't really using this in a supported country. However, you can fake it by going to Settings > Video input > Configured devices > (whatever your TV source is) > Edit channel lineup and then go through the prompts. This will download the list of channels for your connected set top box (again, this is probably not going to be your real lineup, but enough for you to test out the sample.